# Import a photo from an external scanner to my iOS app directly

Tags: ios, import, scanning

I would like to import a photo or pdf into my app by an external scanner.

I know there are apps made by printer manufacturers to wirelessly import photos into your photos library. After the photo is in there, it is simple to import to my app. However, I would like to do it all within my app.

Are there any open standards to do this? Is there any way to do this with a UIWebView? What about connecting the device to a scanner via USB and somehow saving the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the scanner connected to a server wich will receive each file you scan. With the iphone you can download the data from server.

Hope it helps,
**Mário**